# Removing curly quotes from filenames using Batch

Tags: batch-file

One of our Windows servers processes files and sends them over a network, but when there are special characters such as curly quotes in the filenames they break. Example:
“This_person’s_file”.jpg

I'm trying to write a batch script that will rename the files to remove such special characters. I've seen a lot of scripts that remove ampersands and such but couldn't find any batch scripts that will take care of the above.

Stupid idea? Yes. Do I need to do it in Batch? Yes.

Comment: Please clarify "batch script".  Do you mean a .vbs/.wsh script or something else?